# Facebook R.Java and My Application R.Java conflicts with each other in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-studio, r.java-file

I want to include *Facebook analytics* in my project, but whenever I try to add it, it gives me following error.

> Error:(2892, 33) error: variable bottom is already defined in class id

I Search this variable in the entire project, I found it in two files.
One is in my application/R.java and another is in Facebook/R.java.

I think both R.java files are clashes with each other.I'm using *Android Studio*.

I'm following this link.

https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/386862294991988/?platform=android

Comment: code n stack trace please....

Comment: in Dependencies i'm using this compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'